# how to read files using containers in STL

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, stl, keyvaluepair

I have to read word by word from `"testdata.txt"`and look for the same words in another file `"dictionary.txt"`. I already implemented the code to read the `"dictionary.txt"` in `ReadDictionary()` function. But I have to Implement the `ReadTextFile()` public member function in order to read the file named: `“testdata.txt”` into the “KnownWords” and “UnknownWords” data which are private members.  Only “known” words should be put in the “KnownWords” and the rest to "UnknownWords". 
I have to use map and pair but i have no idea how to use it in my programming. Can someone please help me figure this one out in order to get this output:

```
89 known words read.
49 unknown words read.
```

int main():

```
WordStats ws;
ws.ReadTxtFile();
```

HeaderFile:

```
using namespace std;
typedef map<string, vector<int> > WordMap;     
typedef WordMap::iterator WordMapIter;        

class WordStats
{
public:
    WordStats();
    void ReadDictionary();
    void DisplayDictionary();
    void ReadTxtFile();
private:
    WordMap KnownWords;
    WordMap UnknownWords;
    set<string> Dictionary;
    char Filename[256];
};
```

This is my program:

```
WordStats::WordStats(){
strcpy(Filename,"testdata.txt");
}

// Reads dictionary.txt into Dictionary
void WordStats::ReadDictionary(){
    string word;    
    ifstream infile("dictionary.txt");
    if(!infile)
    {
        cerr << "Error Opening file 'dictionary.txt. " <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while(getline(infile,word))
    {       
        transform (word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        Dictionary.insert(word); 
    }
    infile.close();
    cout << endl;
    cout << Dictionary.size() << " words read from dictionary. \n" <<endl;

}
// Reads textfile into KnownWords and UnknownWords
void WordStats::ReadTxtFile(){
    string words;
    vector<string> findword;
    vector<int> count;
    ifstream ifile(Filename);
    if(!ifile)
    {
        cerr << "Error Opening file 'dictionary.txt. " <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while(!ifile.eof())
    {
        getline(ifile,words);
        //KnownWords.insert( pair<string,int>( KnownWords, words ) );
        findword.push_back(words);
        Paragraph = KnownWords.find(words);
        //stuck here
    }
    }
```

Comment: What `std::vector<int>` values are you associating with your known and  unknown words?

Comment: as per requirement, we have to use vector<int> to push_back the position where we find the word in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need to inspect Dictionary to see if it contains each word you read, then choose which of `KnownWords` and `UnknownWords` to modify.

```
void WordStats::ReadTxtFile(){
    std::ifstream ifile(Filename);
    if(!ifile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error Opening file " << Filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

I have cleaned up your local declarations, so variables are alive for as little time as necessary.

Assuming that the file contains words separated by spaces and newlines, read each word

```
    for (std::string word; ifile >> word; )
    {
```

Make it lowercase

```
        transform (word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Then look to see if it is in `Dictionary`

```
        if (Dictionary.count(word))
        {
```

Record the position in `KnownWords[word]`.

```
            KnownWords[word].push_back(ifile.tellg());
        }
        else
        {
```

Or in `UnknownWords[word]`.

```
            UnknownWords[word].push_back(ifile.tellg()); 
        }
    }
```

Then display the `size`s from those to get the desired output.

```
    std::cout << KnownWords.size() << " known words read." << std::endl;
    std::cout << UnknownWords.size() << " unknown words read." << std::endl;
}
```

You could replace the conditional statement that duplicates the action, with a conditional expression. Note the reference type in the declaration of `Words`

```
WordMap & Words = (Dictionary.count(word) ? KnownWords : UnknownWords);
Words[word].push_back(ifile.tellg());
```

As a complete function:

```
void WordStats::ReadTxtFile(){
    std::ifstream ifile(Filename);
    if(!ifile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error Opening file " << Filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (std::string word; ifile >> word; )
    {
        transform (word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        WordMap & Words = (Dictionary.count(word) ? KnownWords : UnknownWords);
        Words[word].push_back(ifile.tellg()); 
    }

    std::cout << KnownWords.size() << " known words read." << std::endl;
    std::cout << UnknownWords.size() << " unknown words read." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, i have a *particular hatred* of functions like `void MyClass::doAction()`, because they don't use the type system to tell you anything about what is going on. Ask your instructor why they chose those as the members of `WordStats`, over something like `WordStats ReadFromStream(std::istream & source, std::set<std::string> Dictionary)`

Comment: I tried the code but its not giving me the exact output. what should i write inside count() in cout << KnownWords.count() and cout<< UnknownWords.count().. as compiler is giving me this error ` [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> >::count()'`.

Comment: the output is zero for both if i put "word" in it like KnownWords.count(word) or UnknownWords.count(word).

Comment: oops, I meant 'size'

Comment: and how to print out the position of the KnownWord and UnkownWord ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using a wrong datatype `WordMap`. In my humble opinion it should be just `map<string, int>`, because you want to count how many times a word occurs in your text.

Secondly, you should read words from the file instead of whole lines of text. You can do it with following code:

```
std::string word;
while (ifile >> word) {
    if (Dictionary.find(word) != Dictionary.end()) {
        // WordMap::value_type ... creates instance of std::pair object
        auto it = KnownWords.insert(KnownWords.end(), WordMap::value_type(word, 0));
        it->second++;
    } else {
        auto it = UnknownWords.insert(UnknownWords.end(), WordMap::value_type(word, 0));
        it->second++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are yo using "it" for?

Comment: it gives me warning " 'it' does not name a type" I tried to put 'Paragraph' as an iterator it gave me the same error message.

Comment: `it` is an iterator. And if your compiler don't support keyword `auto` you should upgrade it or enable C++11 support.

Comment: I tried and now compiler is giving me this error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> >::pair(std::string&, int)'